# Async/Await Calls within Google Firestore Cloud Functions (using Clearbit Company API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm building a simple react app to store public company data with a Firebase backend and cloud functions. I want to write a onCreate cloud function to pull in additional company data from Clearbit’s API (https://clearbit.com/docs#api-reference). Here is the summary from Clearbit's docs on how to do this:

```
const clearbit = require('clearbit')(api-key);

clearbit.Company.find({domain: 'segment.com'}).then(function (company) {
  console.log('Name: ', company.name);
});
```

I want to convert this to await/async and have done so like this:

```
const getEmployerData = (domain) => {
  async function fetch() {
    try {
      const response = await clearbit.Company.find({ domain: domain });
      console.log(response)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("fetch failed", err);
    }
    return response;
  }
  fetch();
};
```

I can confirm the clearbit.Company.find() is working because the above console.log returns the following:

```
response=  Resource {
  options: {},
  id: 'f3514cf8-c3c1-4eb4-be6a-13604de59c8b',
  name: 'Segment',
  legalName: 'Segment.io Inc',
  domain: 'segment.com',
  domainAliases: [ 'segment.io' ],
  description: 'Segment is a customer data platform (CDP) that helps you collect, clean, and control your customer data.',
  ...
   }
```

I call getEmployerData within my cloud function like so:

```
exports.updateEmployerData = functions.firestore
  .document("/employers/{documentId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const employerId = context.params.documentId;
    const url = snap.get("url");
    const employerDataFromClearbit = await getEmployerData(url);
    const employerRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("employers")
      .doc(employerId);

    return await employerRef.update({
      description: employerDataFromClearbit.description;
    });
  });
```

However, getEmployerData() returns undefined and my update functions fails. Not sure why I am unable to access the company data returned by Clearbit in my cloud function and appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue: `response` is declared inside the `try` but returned outside where it's not defined. Try instead to declare it outside the try:

```
const getEmployerData = (domain) => {
  async function fetch() {
    let response; // <-- declare it here
    try {
      response = await clearbit.Company.find({ domain: domain });
      console.log(response)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("fetch failed", err);
    }
    return response; // so that it's still in scope here
  }
  return fetch(); // per @danh's answer below!
};
```

For more about scope see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const
and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Thanks, I tried this out and still ran into the same error. But your comment about scope got me thinking that I need to pull the getEmployerData into the exported cloud function updateEmployerData.

Comment: @see danh's answer below - I think that you need both what I wrote here and his answer as well - I'll update my answer to include his suggestion as well.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work finally. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

`getEmployerData` doesn't return anything. Try...

```
// ...
return fetch()
```